# While DataGridView was Updating scroll goes up everytime

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scrollbar

I have a gridView in a windows form application. I have to update it's content when we add new row to database. I use that way, to add new row and update it. But when I have content which cannot fit into a page, scroll is visible. When I slide the scroll bottom of  the page and when it update same time, scroll goes top of the page, How can I solve the problem.

```
private void fillhistoryOfUpdateProcessDataGridView()
{
    dt = db.getHistoryOfUpdatedProcess();    

    dgwHistoryofProcess.Invoke(new Action(() => dgwHistoryofProcess.DataSource = dt));

    dgwHistoryofProcess.Invoke(new Action(() => dgwHistoryofProcess.Columns["islemAdi"].HeaderText = "İşlem Adı"));

    dgwHistoryofProcess.Invoke(new Action(() => dgwHistoryofProcess.Columns["islemBaslangicTarihi"].HeaderText = "İşlem Başlangıç Tarihi"));
    dgwHistoryofProcess.Invoke(new Action(() => dgwHistoryofProcess.Columns["islemBitisTarihi"].HeaderText = "İşlem Tamamlanma Tarihi"));
    dgwHistoryofProcess.Invoke(new Action(() => dgwHistoryofProcess.Columns["islemBitisTarihi"].ValueType = typeof(DateTime)));               
    dgwHistoryofProcess.Sort(dgwHistoryofProcess.Columns["islemBitisTarihi"], ListSortDirection.Descending);
    dgwHistoryofProcess.Invoke(new Action(() => dgwHistoryofProcess.Columns["islemDurumu"].HeaderText = "İşlem Durumu"));
    dgwHistoryofProcess.Invoke(new Action(() => dgwHistoryofProcess.Columns["hataLog"].HeaderText = "Hata Sebebi"));

    dgwHistoryofProcess.Invoke(new Action(() => dgwHistoryofProcess.Update()));

    dt.Dispose();
}

private void updateHistoryofUpdatedProcessDataGridView()
{
    dt = db.GuncellemeIslemGecmisiGetir();

    dgwIslemGecmisi.Invoke(new Action(() => dgwIslemGecmisi.DataSource = dt));

    dgwIslemGecmisi.Invoke(new Action(() => dgwIslemGecmisi.Update()));
    dt.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: I'm so sorry, I have add it without code by a mistake. Thanks you for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that before update you find the current row of the `DataGridView`. Then after Update set the position to that record again. It will be easier if you use a `bindingSource` as well. The pseudo-code is like this:

```
private void updateHistoryofUpdatedProcessDataGridView()
{
    var current = bindingSource.Current as typeOfData

    // do the update


    int index = bindingSource.Find("ID", current.ID);
    bindingSource.Position = index;

}
```

However I guess there should be a better way so I am following this question for other answers.

Comment: Finding scroll current position is help to me to solve problem a little bit. Thank you @roozbeh S

Comment: @setniparis glad this helped you. Plz accept the answer